# in `f2py`: how to setting default arrays for optional input

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a fortran function that I want to make available in python. It should have the keyword `weights`:

- if `weights` is **not** given, it should be initialized as being of shape `(nx, 1)` and initialized with values `1.0`.
- if `weights` **is** given as keyword, for example of shape `(nx, 10)`, then its shape should be used inside the subroutine, without having to specify that shape specifically (i.e. without setting `ncols=10`).

Here's my minimal (non-sense) example:

This is the fortran file `ftest.f90`

```
subroutine test_optional(x, y, weights, npoints, ncols)
    implicit none
    integer :: npoints, ncols
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(npoints)
    double precision, intent(out) :: y(npoints)
    !f2py integer :: ncols = 1
    !f2py double precision, optional, intent(in) :: weights(npoints, ncols) = 1.0
    double precision, intent(in) :: weights(npoints, ncols)
    integer :: i

    y = x
    do i = 1, ncols
        y = y + weights(:, i)
    end do

end subroutine test_optional
```

I compile it with `f2py` like this

```bash
!f2py -m fmod -c ftest.f90
```

and import that in python

```py
import fmod
```

This one works if no weigths are given, a default value of 1 is used

```py
x = np.ones(5)
fmod.test_optional(x)

>>> array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
```

This one works, but should work also without giving `ncols=2`

```py
x = np.ones(5)
weights = np.ones([len(x), 2])
fmod.test_optional(x, weights=weights, ncols=2)
>>> array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])
```

However calling without the keyword gives an error:

```py
fmod.test_optional(x, weights=weights)
>>>ValueError: failed in converting 1st keyword `weights' of fmod.test_optional to C/Fortran array
```

How can I tell `f2py` that if `weights` is given, it should determine `ncols=10`?